# Google Sheets onEdit(e) dynamic sort function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you in advance for reading my post and offering suggestions.

Fun disclosure, I found the snippet of code on the internet and tried to adopt it to my needs, I don't intend to plagiarize anyone's work.

I invoke the following from my onEdit function but is does not do anything at all. I want to sort the table in ascending chronologically order based on column 12 which is a date field, as this field is updated in real time.

```
function onEdit(e) { SortApptDate(e); }

function SortApptDate(e) {
  var sheet = 'Sheet1';
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({ column: 12, ascending: true });
}
```

Thank you again.
Jim

Comment: Can you please share a Spreadsheet as example? It'd be helpful for the community members to better understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `sheet` is not the sheet object. By this, the script is not run. An error occurs. In your situation, the event object can be used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) { SortApptDate(e); }

function SortApptDate(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1") {
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({ column: 12, ascending: true });
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, when "Sheet1" is edited, the script for sorting is run.
- When you edited cell in "Sheet1", `range` is sorted with the column "L" as the ascending sort.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Hello - THANK YOU so much. This works as I requested! When using it in a real life, my table has 21 columns, so what happens is as soon as a date is entered in column 12, the table resorts, and the cursor and row that is being worked on moves and is difficult to locate again to finish entering the rest of the data in the row. Instead of an "onEdit" function, is there a function that is invoked once all the data in the row is entered and that row is no longer being edited (cursor moves off the row or the row it completed)?? I hope I described that clearly. The knowledge in this forum is unreal!

Comment: @James Woods Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But it seems that the situation of Spreadsheet of your new question is different from that of your this question. In this case, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?